# Send mail without server side code

Tags: html, email

Is there way where I can send a simple email to any end user using my site using my html code... Considering that my server supports only html and no other server side code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be exact there is no way where you send a mail directly send a mail via html.... However if you have any other server which supports any server side script, you can write a generic ajax functionality which sends a mail and keep its access open, and call the functionality via javascript from your html code... Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you're forgetting about mailto: links; they are 100% client-side.

Comment: That would constitute cross site scripting which is blocked by most browsers (xss)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mailto:` url's that will open the user's mail client if the browser is so configured:

```
<a href="mailto:test@domain.com">Send mail</a>
```

You can also specify the E-Mail's body and some headers. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) for details.

that however is pretty much it. This only opens an E-Mail with the address pre-set; the user will have to send the message, and the mail will have their sender address. There is no other way.

Comment: AFAIK it's also possible to set a `mailto:` as the action for a form. This gives you a bit more control about the contents of the mail. I wouldn't recommend using that though.