# sending mail from html pages as sending through C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I used to send email in **asp.net(using c# code)**
there i used to design form in aspx page and used to write coading in aspx.cs page like

```
        string mailto;
        string mailfrom;
        string name;
        string subject;
        string message;
        string MailContent;
        string cc;
        SmtpClient client;
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg;           
        client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;//25
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;            
        mailto ="abc@gmail.com";
        mailfrom = "noreply@gmail.com";
        name = "name";
        subject = "subject";
        message ="hi";
        msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(mailto);
        //msg.To.Add(cc);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(mailfrom, name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            MailStatus = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            MailStatus = false;
        }
```

But i want to send mail from simple **.html page** similar as above done in **.aspx page**?
is there any kind of **javascript** or **css** or **dll** file which i can use to send an email?

Comment: If you use php ..you can easily write mail sending script in a php tag in your html page

Answer (score 3):

You need to have some mail client to send email. Similar question in the below links

[Send mail without server side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463867/send-mail-without-server-side-code)

[Can we create Contact form using HTML and send mails without Server side programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160080/can-we-create-contact-form-using-html-and-send-mails-without-server-side-program)

Comment: it will open my microsoft outlook box

Comment: yeah, that is the concept. you can not send an email from an html page - you can open a new mail window where you fill in to,subject,body fields and let the user decide if he submits.

Answer (score 1):

A HTML page is static, all a HTML page is, are the bones of the website, e.g. the structure that makes the website's skin 'design' look good.

If you want to send mail, you should do this via a .aspx or .php page, as shown you have some experience with .aspx so I would go with that. Do know that if you are setting up your own server, you will also need a mailserver to be set up and this is usually a pain in the butt to do.

Your only solution for a static page is to either call Ajax with a PHP script, or use a simple `mailto:` href, however the latter will only work when an e-mail program is actually installed and accesible to the user, so this will not work 100% of the time, since people will use webmail (e.g. gmail etc..)